# Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/characters' from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy:

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, api, cors

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/characters' from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Hello, this is my first time setting up a rails api that connnects to react and I am getting this error any help is appreciated

config/initializers/cors.rb

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
   allow do
     origins "http://localhost:3001/"

     resource "*",
       headers: :any,
       methods: [:get, :post, :put, :patch, :delete, :options, :head]
   end
 end
```

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import imageTwo from './components/Waldo-Two.jpg'
import GameBoard from './components/GameBoard';
import axios from "axios";
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';






const API_URL = "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/characters";



function getAPIData(){
  return axios.get(API_URL).then((response) => response.data)
}




function App() {

  const [characters, setCharacters] = useState([])
const [foundWaldo, setFoundWaldo] = useState(false)

useEffect(() => {

  let mounted = true;

  getAPIData().then((person) => {

    if(mounted)
    {
      setCharacters(person)
    }

  });


  return () => (mounted = false);


}, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {foundWaldo ? <h1>Winner!!!!!!!!</h1> : <h1>Welcome Challenger</h1>
      }
      <p>In order to beat this game you must find 
        all the characters in the picture by clicking on them
        at the end your time will be recorded and you will be placed
        on a leaderboard</p>
        <img src = {imageTwo} alt = "Waldo" className='main-image'/>
      <div>
     < GameBoard
      characters = {characters}
      foundWaldo = {foundWaldo}
      setFoundWaldo = {setFoundWaldo}/>
     </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Yeh I think its the trailing slash. It should be `origins "http://localhost:3001"`

Comment: Heads up - the contents of that file is JSX and not Javascript. You can't put "bare" HTML into a JS file.